# Java - mysql access denied error for user with no password

Tags: java, mysql

In command line when I type:

```
mysql -u ebtam -p
```

I see text:

```
 Enter password:
```

When I simply press ENTER, I see the **mysql>** , so I am successfully logged in without a password.

In Java however when I try:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebtam";
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "ebtam";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "";
```

I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I know my code is fine because when I try

```
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "root";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "myPasswordHere";
```

Everything works fine..

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the code that actually attempts to make the connection?

Comment: In your default url, you have mentioned "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebtam" , here, 'ebtam' is your username, but it should specify the name of the database here, did you try putting your db name here?

Comment: Database name is "ebtam" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Pass null as password instead of an empty String. That should make it work.

```
private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebtam";
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "ebtam";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = null;
```

try this it may it will help full for you

Comment: Thanks, I will try once I find time.